# Why i get wrong result set mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, where-clause

EDIT Attention! i know its looks confusing but answer of steveo 
SELECT * from orders Group by orderId having masterId = 29 
help me , i just dont undestand how does it work

I dont undestand what is going on , i just get wrong result
i have table orders that looks lile this:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int NOT NULL,
  `masterId` int NOT NULL,
  `serviceId` int NOT NULL,
  `startTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timeSlotId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `isApplied` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `isDone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`),
  KEY `FK_user` (`userId`),
  KEY `FK_master` (`masterId`),
  KEY `FK_timeSlotOrder` (`timeSlotId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_master` FOREIGN KEY (`masterId`) REFERENCES `masters` (`masterId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_timeSlotOrder` FOREIGN KEY (`timeSlotId`) REFERENCES `time_slot` (`timeSlotId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_user` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user_info` (`userId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

and now i have two rows in a table :
[image: bug mysql]

and when i make this select command i get correct result set:
[image: Correct result set]

but when i specify id of master(masterId column in order table) i get only one result despite there should be two orders [image]
i just dont undestand why is that happening
Thanks

Comment: The data type is indicated as INT, but the numbers are showing up aligned to the left hand side of the column. Is that normal?

Comment: @Strawberry i dont know , are you asking? but its confusing me

Comment: Suffice to say, I cannot replicate this observation. :-( https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n6XpUtTEroz8dpxVmURJY9/0

Comment: @Strawberry, i saw your answer i know it looks confusing but  answer of steveo314 helped me despite not where but a having statement were used

Comment: I very much doubt that that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT *
FROM salon.orders
GROUP BY orderId
HAVING masterId = 29
```

Comment: not where but having statement help me thanks, how did you know?

Comment: i can mark your question if you change it to having because it hepls me

Comment: `HAVING masterId = 29` is what corrected your code?

Comment: Yes but how?orderId`s are different how did you know that group by will work?

Comment: GROUP BY lets you use duplicate IDs in the same field

Comment: but orderId`s are different arent they?

Comment: so its mysql thing to not show duplicates or why i need to use Group By to see them?

Comment: A lot of programming languages will overwrite duplicate keys unless you say not to